# Can someone explain what's going on in this for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, palindrome

Also please include a tracetable that shows the values of each variable at each position. Thanks. When it returns true, it says that the array is a palindrome. When it returns false, it says that the array is not a palindrome. The code works, but I just need an explanation of why or how it works.

```
var x = readNumberOfEntries();
                var w = new Array(x);
                for (var y = 0; y < x; y++) {
                    var z = Number(prompt("Enter entry"));
                    w[y] = z;

                }
                var r = w.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < (r/2); i++) {
                    if (w[i] !== w [r-1-i]) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What specific part don't you understand?

Comment: Just go ahead and post all of your homework so we can answer all of them for you at once. It'll be more efficient that way.

Comment: The first loop fills in an array of numbers, and then, to see if an array is a palindrome, you should compare the first number and the last one, and then pass to the second number and the one before the last one.. and so on, that's why the code has (r/2), so it'll divide the array for two part and compare number by number. You should take examples of your own and try to run the loop yourself.

Comment: @Igor  I just needed an explanation of the second for loop

Comment: I mean like how do programmers pretty much come up with the necessary experssions to be put in the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for-loop fills an array of length x with user entered values.

Second for-loop checks for array like this [1,2,3,3,2,1].
So it checks wether the array is reversev in the second half.

Though because of the return the for-loop will be canceled at first run.

So if the first entry of the array equals the last it will return true, otherwise false.